# Integrating Apple Pay JS Into A Website

Tags: html, applepay, applepayjs

I'm looking into integrating Apple Pay into a website using the new [Apple Pay JS](https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs) SDK. The documentation is currently pretty minimal, concerning just the API declarations and how to instantiate a new `ApplePaySession` object.

Is there any example code available yet, or has anyone actually implemented this themselves yet, showing the typical API integration flow for a web application?

The only examples I've been able to find anything for all appear to be for third-party payment providers' own SDK integrations of Apple Pay.

Comment: A video about how to implement Apple Pay using the JS SDK is now available here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/703/

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but where can I find the download to applepay.js? Or is it somehow available in XCode?

Comment: @nils It's built into the Safari browser in the same way "window" is built into browsers. There's no .js files to pull in.

Comment: I see, thank you. It is really poorly documented :/

Comment: Indeed... I'm planning on doing a blog post about the implementation I've been working on once the design is finalised and it's working end-to-end.

Comment: Could you please post the link here once you've written it?

Comment: To avoid frustration if it isn't obvious: for now and in the future Apple Pay JS will only be available on IOS 10 or later. As others have said the API is built into Safari which (unfortunately) corresponds to iOS version and cannot be updated independently. This is why it's important to hide Apple Pay buttons until you can verify that `ApplePaySession.canMakePayments()` is available

Comment: I'm still working on my implementation, but I've found this GitHub repo useful in providing some assistance on implementing the client authentication with the Apple Pay servers: https://github.com/tomdale/apple-pay-merchant-session-server. The Apple Pay JS documentation has also been recently updated with more detail: https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs.

Comment: Additionally, here's a "working demo" with the pieces together: https://justindonnelly.github.io/applepayjs/

Comment: even today - iOS10 release date it looks like somebody just stopped halfway through documenting it. ugh

Comment: Even today in 2019 - It sucks to integrate and proper documentation

Comment: Phoning in from 2020 ... same sparse docs and complete lack of good movement from Apple on this.

Comment: I'm back and I miss 2016. Now there's a JS file referenced without explanation to have to contend with - and zero explanation as to why I would use it over the built in css. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/displaying_apple_pay_buttons_using_javascript

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've published end-to-end ApplePayJS example code on github here

https://github.com/norfolkmustard/ApplePayJS

It uses PHP for the server-side part, needed for the  initial vendor validation to begin the transaction. The rest is in javascript.

ApplePayJS != cash in the bank, just a means of getting a tokenised credit card from a customer. You hand that card number off to a third-party payment processor like stripe.com, braintreepayments.com, authorize.net

Cheers

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you. Apple's video on the matter didn't make clear exactly what was going on during the onvalidatemerchant promise, but your example is what I assumed but wasn't sure of.

Comment: This may be 2 years old but it's still the only bit of example code that actually filled in the last piece of the puzzle for me for getting a merchant session from Apple. Many thanks Stu.

Comment: The apple pay payment session url is: https://apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession as of Dec 2019, /paymentServices/paymentSession is not working at least for me.

Comment: If I want to integrate payment gateway with apple pay and want to do parallel payment on it so is it possible to do?

Answer (score 9):

The stable release will be available this fall probably.

First thing you want to do is to ensure that API is available in your browser:

```
if(ApplePaySession)
   ApplePaySession.canMakePayments()
```

Then the transaction itself:

```
var request = {
  countryCode: 'US',
  currencyCode: 'USD',
  supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'masterCard'],
  merchantCapabilities: ['supports3DS'],
  total: { label: 'Your Label', amount: '10.00' },
}
var session = new ApplePaySession(1, request);
```

This is from official website how to get it started: https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs/applepaysession

After you have the session, you can control it:
[image]

And you can listen to events, and change your flow based on it:
[image]

I'm working on the integration between Apple Pay JS and Stripe API right now, so I'll release draft version to [GitHub](https://github.com/eugenehp/applepayjs) this summer.

Comment: Additionally, here's a "working demo" with the pieces together: https://justindonnelly.github.io/applepayjs/

Comment: @PaulIrish Nice, you managed to get the Apple Pay button working nicely. I've had trouble with that (it crashed the tab in beta 2...).

Comment: Unfortunately, this demo is no longer / not working and gives _The type of an object was incompatible with the expected type of the parameter associated to the object_ as error. I wonder is this is due to changes made in the iOS public beta?

Comment: @Martin what kind of iOS/OS X build you are using?

Comment: Beta 3 made some properties deprecated "AddresesFields" -> "ContactFields". It's possible that those are now errors, instead of warnings.

Comment: I'm using iOS 10 b 5 and also tried it with and without Content Blockers. No luck...

Answer (score 7):

The integration I've been working on has now finally been released, and there's a [blog post](http://tech.just-eat.com/2016/10/10/bringing-apple-pay-to-the-web/) I've written to go along with it as well as a [GitHub project](https://github.com/justeat/ApplePayJSSample) with an example integration using ASP.NET Core.

I hope others doing an Apple Pay JS integration themselves find it useful.